# Mutate Paste0 Min Max to create new id variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create an id that defines the relationship between contact_id and relationship_id into a common household_id if and where the combination of contact_id and relationship_id are the same.

Sample Data

```
account_id <- c(1,1,1,1)
contact_id <- c(1234,2345,3456,4567)
relationship_id <- c(2345,1234,NA,"")
ownership_percent <- c(26,22,40,12)
score <- c(500,300,700,600)
testdata <- data.frame(account_id,contact_id,relationship_id,ownership_percent,score)
```

Have been using combinations of mutate, paste0, min, max, group_indices - have not found the right combination, getting tripped up by NA and order output of new household_id

Approach 1

```
  library(dplyr)
    testdata %>%
      mutate(col1 = pmin(contact_id, relationship_id), 
             col2 = pmax(contact_id, relationship_id),
             household_id = paste0(col1,col2)) %>%
```

Approach 2

```
 testdata %>%
    mutate(household_id = sort(paste0(c(contact_id, relationship_id))), collapse = "")
```

Error: Column `household_id` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 8

Expected Outcome

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
# replace missing or NA values with 1
testdata$relationship_id <- type.convert(testdata$relationship_id)
testdata$relationship_id[relationship_id == ""] <- 1
testdata$relationship_id[is.na(testdata$relationship_id)] <- 1

# Create household_id
testdata %>%
  mutate(group = paste0(pmin(contact_id, relationship_id), pmax(contact_id, relationship_id)), 
         household_id = match(group, unique(group)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

testdata %>%
  mutate(col1 = pmin(contact_id, relationship_id, na.rm = TRUE), 
         col2 = pmax(contact_id, relationship_id, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(household_id = paste0(unique(c(col1, col2)), collapse = '')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-col1, -col2)

#  account_id contact_id relationship_id ownership_percent score household_id
#       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
#1          1       1234 "2345"                         26   500 12342345    
#2          1       2345 "1234"                         22   300 12342345    
#3          1       3456  NA                            40   700 3456        
#4          1       4567 ""                             12   600 4567
```